# How to load object depending on a input$select

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to load a R object in a Shiny app. I have 2 objects, and depending on which option user selected, I need to load one or another.

I can load one object if I call the load object outside `shinyServer(function(input, output) {})`

But I need load it inside, depending on the user selected option.

My code is like:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$select,{
                if(input$select==1){
                        DT1<-load(file = 'DT1N', envir=.GlobalEnv)
                }else DT1<-load(file = 'DT1B', envir=.GlobalEnv)
        }
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `observeEvent` which doesn't return any value (and is used for side effects), use `eventReactive` which is about the same but the difference is that it does return a value. You can then access it with `DT1()`.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  DT1 <- eventReactive(input$select,{
    if(input$select==1){
      return(load(file = 'DT1N', envir=.GlobalEnv))
    }else return(load(file = 'DT1B', envir=.GlobalEnv))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks!

But I have still one question.

What if I need to load two or more objects?

I can create a vector, but the objects are heavy and It's not efficient....

Any suggestion?

Thank you again!

Comment: If your data is huge then you can use `dplyr` or  `data.table` Packages for more efficient data manipulation. [Speed comparision](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/09/a-speed-test-comparison-of-plyr-data-table-and-dplyr/)